# How to count items in list of lists

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How i can find length of each item in a `"mol"`list:

For example if I am looking for `"versionA" : "2.1.2"` I expect ot get following result:

```
{"project" : "A", "scene" : 13455312, mol:[3,2,1]},
{"project" : "B", "scene" : 13455344, mol:[3,3,3]}
```

My data:

```
{
        "project" : "A",
        "scene" : 13455312,
        "versionA" : "2.1.2",
        "versionB" : "2.1.9",
        "mol" : [ {"data" : [ { "tran" : 'A' }, { "tran" : 'B' }, { "tran" : 'C' }]}, {"data" : [ { "tran" : 'A' }, { "tran" : 'B' }]}, {"data" : [ { "tran" : 'A' }]}]
    },

    {
        "project" : "B",
        "scene" : 13455344,
        "versionA" : "2.1.2",
        "versionB" : "2.1.9",
        "mol" : [ {"data" : [ { "tran" : 'A' }, { "tran" : 'B' }, { "tran" : 'C' }]}, {"data" : [ { "tran" : 'A' }, { "tran" : 'B' }, { "tran" : 'C' }]}, {"data" : [ { "tran" : 'A' }, { "tran" : 'B' }, { "tran" : 'C' }]}]
    },
    {
        "project" : "C",
        "scene" : 135555,
        "versionA" : "2.1.3",
        "versionB" : "2.1.9",
        "mol" : [ {"data" : [ { "tran" : 'A' }]}, {"data" : [ { "tran" : 'A' }]}, {"data" : [ { "tran" : 'A' }]}]
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `$match` to the `version` field and `$map` which iterates the `mol` and `$size` to calculate the the length of data field.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [{
        $match: {
            "versionA": "2.1.2"
        }
    }, {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            "project": 1,
            "scene": 1,
            "mol": {
                $map: {
                    input: "$mol",
                    as: "mo",
                    in: {
                        $size: "$$mo.data"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }]
)
```

Comment: Thanks exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way of doing it as well:

First you `$map` each element of "mol", inside that you reduce each element of mol to the size of it's inside array using `$reduce`.

```
db.stack.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { "versionA": "2.1.2" }    
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            "project": 1,
            "scene": 1,
            mol: {
                $map: {
                  input: "$mol",
                  as: "ob",
                  in: {
                      $reduce: {
                            input: "$$ob.data",
                            initialValue: 0,
                            in: { $add: ["$$value", 1] }  
                      }
                  }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]);
```